# MongoDB store and query price history

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm working with a set of data which is a product catalog. There's only about 20k items, and price change occurs rarely. Maybe 100 updates per month, at most.

However, price change is the interesting thing in this case, and I want to track prices over long periods of time.

I'm trying to find the best way to store the price data in a way that makes it easy to query.

Currently it's stored in an array on the product document. Simply the price along with a timestamp. Given the small and fairly static set of data, how would you design the model?

Also, bonus question, what would a filter look like that could give a list of products where the current price is lower than the previous one?

Example data, simplified version of the model:

```
// Match, current price is lower than previous price

db.TestC.insert({Name: "P1", CurrentPrice: 10.0,  PriceHistory: [{Price: 14.0, Timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-26T07:11:11.939Z")}, {Price: 12.0, Timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-27T07:11:11.939Z")}]})

// No match, price history doesn't exist yet

db.TestC.insert({Name: "P2", CurrentPrice: 10.0, PriceHistory: null})

// No match, previous price was lower than current price

db.TestC.insert({Name: "P3", CurrentPrice: 18.0, PriceHistory: [{Price: 14.0, Timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-26T07:11:11.939Z")}, {Price: 12.0, Timestamp: ISODate("2019-04-27T07:11:11.939Z")}]})
```

Edit after some more work on this:

So, I finally came up with exactly what I needed and thought I should share in case it helps someone:

```
db.TestCollection.aggregate({
    '$project': {
      'Number': 1, 
      'AssortmentKey': 1, 
      'AssortmentName': 1, 
      'NameExtension': 1, 
      'Name': 1, 
      'CurrentPrice': {
        '$arrayElemAt': [
          '$PriceHistory', -1
        ]
      }, 
      'PreviousPrice': {
        '$arrayElemAt': [
          '$PriceHistory', -2
        ]
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      '$expr': {
        '$lt': [
          '$CurrentPrice.Price', '$PreviousPrice.Price'
        ]
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would organize the documents in the same way actually. Just keep in mind that MongoDB has hard limit of 16 MBs per document, which is very very high limit, almost unreachable in such case, but still it exists.

If you need to only know current price without history, you can query using projection, to avoid sending that huge array over network:

```js
db.TestC.find({Name: 'P1'}, {Name, CurrentPrice}});
```

As for the bonus question, you can leverage the aggregation framework:

```js
db.TestC.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      Name: 1,
      CurrentPrice: 1,
      PreviousPrice: { // remove this key if you don't need to have previous price in the result
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$PriceHistory",
          0 // depends on whether you store prices by pushing to the end of history array, or to the beginning of it
        ]
      },
      IsCurrentPriceLower: {
        $lt: [
          "$CurrentPrice",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              "$PriceHistory",
              0 // depends on whether you store prices by pushing to the end of history array, or to the beginning of it
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      IsCurrentPriceLower: true
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Great, thanks! As for the size limit, I don't think that will be an issue :)

Also, I think I need to change lt to gt or swap order of the compared items to get the desired result?